# Cannot install GNOME extensions even resetting configuration

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I recently switched from Ubuntu MATE to Ubuntu GNOME, and the top-left hot corner is bothering me, so I read that I had to install an extension to remove it. I installed the GNOME extension and I went to their website and searched for "No topleft hot corner" extension, and installed it. There is a sign telling me if I want to cancel or install, I click install and nothing happens.

I tried resetting GNOME shell and removing my configuration, but still doesn't work. Anybody has any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to install gnome-shell extensions via http://extension.gnome.org you need both the browser plugin, and the native connector.

For firefox, download the browser plugin from here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/

And, as mentioned in the "About this Add-on" there, install the native connector:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```